# FileReader: reading multiple items; how to set a callback upon reading the last one?

Tags: javascript, drag-and-drop, filereader

I am creating a 'drag and drop' field which can accept files and folders recursively. This is the code:

```
function traverseFileTree(item) {
    if (item.isFile) {
        item.file(function(file) {
            var reader = new FileReader();
            reader.onload = function(evt) {
                // do something...
            };
            reader.readAsText(file);
        });
    } else if (item.isDirectory) {
        var dirReader = item.createReader();
        dirReader.readEntries(function(entries) {
            for (var i = 0; i < entries.length; i++) {
                traverseFileTree(entries[i]);
            }
        });
    }
}

var dropZone = document.getElementById("drop_zone");
dropZone.addEventListener("drop", function(evt) {
    var items = event.dataTransfer.items;
    for (var i = 0; i < items.length; i++) {
        var item = items[i].webkitGetAsEntry();
        if (item) {
            traverseFileTree(item);
        }
    }
}, false);
```

My question: what is the best or perhaps the most elegant way of having a callback upon reading the last file. Since the read is asynchronous, I can not just rely on scope rules. So, is it by use of a counter, or am I missing some cool method here? Thanks!

Answer (score 0):

You could make some sort of counter and check it on the *onload* functions (you may want to have it in the *onerror*, too).

```
function CountDown() {
    this.remain = 0;
}
CountDown.prototype.inc = function (x) {
    if (undefined === x) x = 1;
    this.remain += +x;
    return this;
}
CountDown.prototype.done = function () {
    if (0 >= --this.remain) {
        this.remain = 0;
        return true;
    }
    return false;
}

var count = new CountDown().inc(3); // 3 files
// in the onload for each, test
count.done(); // false
count.done(); // false
count.done(); // true
count.done(); // true
count.done(); // true, etc
```

Of course, this could also be done in your code without the whole object wrapping if you scope the variable properly.

Comment: OK, so first I have to traverse through files to obtain the correct value to pass to **inc** method. But then, how do I callback upon the last file counted, and move on to the rest of the code?

Comment: @eudoxyz I wrote it so you can easily do `.inc()`, `.inc()`, etc instead of all at once, so you call it just before the _read_. The "moving on with code" can be done in the _onload_ or _onerror_ of the _FileReader's_ callback; basically you do `if (count.done()) nextBitOfCode();`

Comment: Thanks. Here's what I did:

        `var reader = new FileReader();
        reader.onload = function(evt) {
         if (!--fileCounter) {
          // do something
         }  
        };
        fileCounter++;
        reader.readAsText(file);`

fileCounter being a global variable. So it does work for now, but it presupposes that the first _onload_ is called after at least two previous reads.

Comment: If you're worried about that, you could defer the _reads_ until after whatever loop creates the _FileReaders_ so you have it all set up, then do a second loop to initiate all the _reads_. Or, if it's writeable as a `for` loop, you may be able to set `fileCounter = n;`